# C++ WinSock: How to know if receiver disconnected

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I have two programs. They are connected via TCP, localhost, and running on the same machine. First is sending a message via send(), and second is receiving via recv(). When second program is terminated(I just stop running it), it doesn't call destructor to close the socket, and the socket is staying opened. Meanwhile program 1 is trying to send message, and doesn't get error(to reconnect), because message is actually being wrote in socket. How to know if program 2 is disconnected?

send() is not returning -1 if program 2 is terminated. I have tried using using WSAPOLLFD

```
    WSAPOLLFD pollfds[1];
    pollfds[0].fd = sockfd;
    pollfds[0].events = POLLOUT | POLLHUP | POLLERR; // Interested in write events, hang-up events, and error events

    int ready = WSAPoll(pollfds, 1, INFINITE); // Wait indefinitely until an event occurs
    if (ready == -1)
    {
        int error = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Error polling response! Error code: " << error << std::endl;
        isConnected = false;
    }
```

and end up getting error code: 10022 every time

Comment: Make program 2 call `shutdown(socket, SD_BOTH);` before exiting. That's the polite way of telling the other side that you disconnect. Close it afterwards, then terminate.

Comment: None of the things you can try give you an ironclad guarantee of having a 100% reliable way of determining that the peer vanished. That's the nature of how sockets work. All network applications must have appropriate logic that takes this fundamental fact into account. Merely relying on send/recv or read/write returning with an error code will always end in tears.

Comment: Remember that TCP/IP was designed to survive Nuclear Armageddon. It will keep trying until either the message goes through or you give up and kill the program. You often need to have timeouts to escape and keep-alive messages to verify whether or not the other side can still respond within that timeout.

Comment: Side note: The above is a sorta-joke. The Internet was modeled on a theoretical system to survive nuclear war, but wasn't really intended to survive it itself.

Comment: More details are needed:  Are you using TCP or UDP?  Also, are the two programs running on the same machine, or on different machines?  Finally, how is the second program being terminated?

Comment: On a side note: [WSAPoll() is broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/) so consider using an alternative, such as overlapped I/O.

Comment: Exiting a program closes its sockets. The operating system does this automatically.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I am using TCP, programs are running on the same machine, connected via local host, AF_INET, and I just stop the program running. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in the special case where the remote program is running on the same host as the local program, it's possible to know for certain when the peer has vanished, because (barring a bug in the OS's networking stack) there is no possibility of the "network" between the programs dropping packets or becoming split into two parts.

Comment: @EdgarKhachatryan FWIW I just tested on my Windows 10 VM with a toy program, and I observed that when I press ctrl-C on the remote peer, the local peer's next call to `send()` returns `-1` and sets `WSAGetLastError()`'s return value to `10054` aka `WSACONNRESET`.  I believe that is the expected behavior; I'm not sure why you aren't seeing the same thing.  You might need to post some example code that other people can compile and run to observe the problem directly, before an answer can be provided.